# Why do Object.keys(this).map(key => (this as any)[key])?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Reviewing [this method](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/master/src/validation/ValidationTypes.ts#L95) and I'm just curious why it uses `Object.keys(this).map(key => (this as any)[key])`?. 
 Would it be just as valid to just call `Object.keys(this).indexOf(type) !== -1`:

```
/**
 * Checks if validation type is valid.
 */
static isValid(type: string) {
    return  type !== "isValid" &&
        type !== "getMessage" &&
        Object.keys(this).map(key => (this as any)[key]).indexOf(type) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: It maps the key to the value, probably for javascript versions that do not support `Object.values` yet.

Comment: @ASDFGerte a browser that supports arrow functions but not `Object.values` ?

Comment: @Derek It's quite possible. `Object.values` is from ES2017. Arrow functions are from ES2015.

Comment: Yes, arrow function came with ES6 (ES2015), `Object.values` came with ES2017

Comment: @CertainPerformance I know its possible, but I don't find it probable, and a simple look at caniuse proves that

Comment: @Derek Arrow functions were part of ES2015, but `Object.values` wasn't included until ES2017.

Comment: I know this. Not the point I was making.

Comment: The typescript target is probably ES6, meaning TSC cannot use `Object.values` but can use arrow functions.

Comment: @ASDFGerte that makes more sense to me

Comment: Hmmm ... That brings up another question ... if Object.values were used, would Typescript compile it down...?

Comment: Looking at it again, my comment doesn't make much sense, as the code is typescript and not transpiled javascript. So i don't know, the person writing it probably just didn't know `Object.values` yet or it was written before it appeared.

Comment: Tried compiling `Object.values()` on the playground, and it still shows `Object.values` on the javascript side, but the playground does not have an option for ES5, so perhaps it will compile it with that option set ... otherwise it's probably a bug ...

Comment: ["TypeScript does not polyfill functionality, it only down-emits syntactical constructs. If you want this functionality in ES5, you will need to use an external polyfill library like core-js."](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8482). @Derek In other words, my previous comment around TSC and `Object.values` is just nonsense, the related code is still typescript and TSC does not polyfill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That line doesn't create an array of the keys of the object, it creates an array of the *values* of the object and checks if `type` is included in the array. It would be clearer if it was

```
/**
 * Checks if validation type is valid.
 */
static isValid(type: string) {
  return  type !== "isValid" &&
    type !== "getMessage" &&
    Object.values(this).includes(type);
}
```

(including polyfills as necessary, of course)

Comment: Ah OK - Got tripped up on the `this as any` part - I assume that `this` inside the map clause is the array then?

Comment: No, the array of values is being created by `Object.values(this)`. No idea what `this` refers to though, there isn't any context for it, I'm assuming it's just some object with key/value pairs

Comment: I meant the `this` from the original example.  IIUC the `this` part when used in `Object.keys(this)` is the prototype for the class that contains the static `isValid` method,   Hmm .. OK ... I think this is always the same thing in either case.  It's always the prototype that corresponds to the class definition IIUC.